# How can I combine the code of two functions with different arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following two functions:

```
function mvcOnFailure(message) {

    $.modal({
        title: "MVC Error",
        closeButton: true,
        content: message,
        ...
    });
}

function ajaxOnFailure(ajaxContext) {

    $.modal({
        title: "Ajax Error",
        closeButton: true,
        content: ajaxContext.responseText,
        ...
    });
}
```

They both do the same thing (some lines omitted) but take different arguments. Is there some way that I could combine these functions. What I am thinking is to somehow have one function to do most of the work such as opening the dialog and then have two others inherit from that.

Comment: It's been changed by a poster now. Sorry for the wrong tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I am thinking is to somehow have one function to do most of the work such as opening the dialog and then have two others inherit from that.

Not *inherit*, but yes, put the common code in a third function and *call* it from the other two. Very roughly:

```
function mvcOnFailure(message) {

    doTheCommonStuff("MVC Error", message /*, other, stuff */);
}

function ajaxOnFailure(ajaxContext) {

    doTheCommonStuff("Ajax Error", ajaxContext.responseText /*, other, stuff */);
}

function doTheCommonStuff(title, content /*, other, stuff */) {
    $.modal({
        title: title,
        closeButton: true,
        content: content
        ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the same function for both callbacks. All you have to do is check your parameter, e.g. in this case I'd try to see whether it's an object or a string (not familiar with MVC, but I think it would be an object).

However this could be tricky (or even impossible) and it can be considered bad coding (essentially passing a controlling variable selecting code to be executed), so keeping the functions but calling a generic function to format/create the output might be the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the `message` parameter is the difference. So, it should be possible to combine both functions in one:

```
function mvcOrAjaxOnFailure(message) {
    $.modal({
        title: message.responseText ? "Ajax (XHR) Error" : "MVC Error",
        closeButton: true,
        content: message.responseText || message,
        ...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ES5 you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) not only to create a new function with a different context object, but also to perform currying(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):

```
function displayModal(title, message) {
    $.modal({
        title: title,
        closeButton: true,
        content: message,
        ...
    });
}

var mvcOnFailure = displayModal.bind(undefined, "MVC Error");
var ajaxOnFailure = displayModal.bind(undefined, "Ajax Error");
```

Now you have two new `displayModal` functions where the first argument (`title`) is already set. So, for instance, when you call:

```
mvcOnFailure("foo");
```

"foo" will be the `message` argument, and `title` automatically "MVC Error".